# No ethernet after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

I did a clean upgrade to 16.04 and even though I have a wired connection, I have the wireless icon in the top right trying to connect but failing.

I've found similar posts but nothing seems to work. Please help!

output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X540-T1
    Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
    Kernel modules: ixgbe
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: You have two Ethernet adapters. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: Found the problem! I was connecting the wrong adapter! Oops, thanks for your help!